# How to say your graduate ranking?

Tags: grammar, american-english

How should I write about my graduation ranking in a formal way?

> I graduated with a 3rd rank.

or

> I graduated with 3rd ranking.

or

> I graduated ranking the 3rd.

or something else. And I can't use the Latin titles. Please let's stick with the numbers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask about US English it is worth pointing out that US educational institutions do not usually use 'rank' when talking about graduation results. If you got the third highest mark you would usually say 'I graduated third in my class'. It would be possible but unusual to say 'I ranked third in my graduating class'.

If you were talking about a hypothetical system where graduates were split into ranks according to result (like the British system of degree classes) you could say 'I graduated in the third rank'.

Answer (score 0):

The use of *rank* or *ranking* sounds strange in this context. (And your third sentence is ungrammatical.)

It normally applies to a different type of situation, such as:

> I'm a black belt of the third rank.

(Although *degree* or *dan* are often also used.)

---

I would not use *rank* when talking about where in a class you graduated.

Instead, I would simply say:

> I graduated third in my class.